# Google API Console page is blank

Tags: google-api

When I try to go to the Google API Console website to get a Google Maps API Key, all I get is a blank page. I've tried [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/aU7aJ3g-jKY), but it didn't work for me. Please help.

[This is what the blank page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQpJ.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the  API console webpage isn't working for you, you can easily go to [this webpage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#key) and scroll down until you see the button that says "GET A KEY." Then follow the steps to create your google maps API key.

Hope this helps!